# How to write common functions to Open and Close database connection?

Tags: function, vba, excel

I'm beginner in Excel VBA and your help is much appreciated.

Please advice how can I create a common function to Open and database connection, and another function to close it, to avoid duplication of coding?

---

Here is my code. I'm stuck on how to move on...

```
Const connection_string As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXX;Persist Security              `Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Data Source=XXXX;"

Sub DuplicateDBConnection()

'Declare variables
Set cn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open Connection
cn1.ConnectionString = connection_string
cn1.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command
Set cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn1
cmd1.CommandText = "Select stock_code, name, sector_id from stock_master"
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd1.Execute

'Open Recordset
Set rs1.ActiveConnection = cn1
rs1.Open cmd1

'Copy Data to Excel
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (rs1)

'Close Connection
rs1.Close
cn1.Close

'Throw Object
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set cn1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

My wish is to write common functions so that I don't need to keep writing code to connect and close connection.

```
Sub ConnectDB()
    'Codes to connect DB
End Sub

Sub CloseConnnection()
    'Codes to close connection
End Sub

Sub ExecuteCode()
    ConnectDB
    'Execute SQL command to manipulate data on excel and SQL database 
    CloseConnection
End Sub
```

---

Edit based on Kittoe's suggestions and works properly now. Thanks!

1. Class:
   a. Created a class called AdoDbHelper, Private Instancing 
   b. In AdoDbHelper, change "Option Compare Database" to "Option Compare Text"
2. Module:
   Create a function like this.

Code below:

```
Const connection_string As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXX;Persist Security              `Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Data Source=XXXX;"

Sub Test()

Dim sourceDb As New AdoDbHelper
Dim sourceRs As New ADODB.Recordset

sourceDb.Connect (connection_string)

Set sourceRs = sourceDb.OpenRecordset("Select stock_code, name, sector_id from     stock_master")

With sourceRs
    'Do stuff!

     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sourceRs

    .Close
End With

sourceDb.Disconnect

Set sourceRs = Nothing
Set sourceDb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What code do you use to open a connection currently

Comment: Yes kindly see my sample codes (which works) and the pseudo codes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

This type of stuff is best done in a class. Right click your VBA project in the "IDE" and go to Insert -> Class Module. Name your class something meaningful like clsAdoHelper (if Hungarian Notation is your thing), AdoDbHelper, or something. The following is an example of the code you'd put in this class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents conn As ADODB.Connection
Private WithEvents rs As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub Connect(ConnectionString As String)
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "A connection is already open."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ConnectionString = CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString Then
        Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Else
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open ConnectionString
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Disconnect()
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        If conn.State <> 0 Then
            conn.Close
        End If

        Set conn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Execute(SQL As String)
    If conn Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No connection open."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    conn.Execute (SQL)
End Sub

Public Function OpenRecordset(SQL As String, Optional CursorLocation As ADODB.CursorLocationEnum = adUseClient, Optional CursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum = adOpenForwardOnly, Optional LockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum = adLockReadOnly) As ADODB.Recordset
    If conn Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No connection open."
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "A recordset is already open."
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rs
        .CursorLocation = CursorLocation
        .CursorType = CursorType
        .LockType = LockType
        .Open SQL, conn
    End With

    Set OpenRecordset = rs
End Function

Public Sub BeginTransaction()
    conn.BeginTrans
End Sub

Public Sub CommitTransaction()
    conn.CommitTrans
End Sub

Public Sub RollbackTransaction()
    conn.RollbackTrans
End Sub

Private Sub conn_BeginTransComplete(ByVal TransactionLevel As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "Transaction started."
End Sub

Private Sub conn_CommitTransComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "Transaction committed."
End Sub

Private Sub conn_ConnectComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)

End Sub

Private Sub conn_Disconnect(adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)

End Sub

Private Sub conn_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "SQL execution complete."
End Sub

Private Sub conn_RollbackTransComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "Transaction rolled back."
End Sub
```

**Using your new class:**

```
Dim sourceDb As New AdoDbHelper
Dim sourceRs as New ADODB.Recordset

sourceDb.Connect (<insert connection string here>)

Set sourceRs = sourceDb.OpenRecordSet(<insert SQL string here>)

With sourceRs
    'Do stuff!

    .Close
End With

sourceDb.Disconnect

Set sourceRs = Nothing
Set sourceDb = Nothing
```

It's not exactly the best code I've ever written but it should give you a decent start. If you have trouble understanding how the class works I encourage you to do a little research on OOP and classes in VBA. You'll notice that you still have a little bit of necessary biolerplate code here but the bulk of the normal work has been taken care of for you in the class methods. If you wanted to put the data manipulation logic into a function of it's own you could pass it the ADODB.Recordset object that you create using the class (this would replace the `WITH` blocks).

I wouldn't suggest polluting the class with such logic as you want the class to handle all of your generic connect/disconnect/exception handling for any possible ADODB connections. That way you can reuse it in other projects =D.

Comment: Thanks Kittoes, kindly check my progress and error messages on top.

Comment: @rpg Are you referencing the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library and the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library?

Comment: @rpg It's hard to tell for sure without being able to sit there and trouble shoot with you but I suggest A. Googling "VBA ADO Class does not support automation" because it appears there are several people who have run into it before and B. Reading: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-38.html. Hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Kittoes it's resolved by changing: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (sourceRS) to ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sourceRs.

Comment: @Kittoes I need help again. I tried to return 2 SQL queries in one Sub, and hence 2 recordsets have to be created. After the 1st recordset, I have set the sourceRS to nothing and close it. However when I run the 2nd recordset, debug message "A recordset is already open." is shown. Is that I need to close the rs opened in the class, and if yes, how? Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library x.x:

In your VBA window go to Tools> References > Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library x.x

I usually use 2.7 for downward compatibility. Now you can create ADODB objects to open connections, perform queries (select/update/delete/...) and use the query results (called record sets) to the rest of your excel, into tables, in specific cells.

To be sure to use the same connection all the time, create a Public connection object and refer to that in all your subroutines. In each subroutine first check if it is already set up by (`conn` being my `ADODB.Connection` object):

```
If conn = Nothing Then Call Setup_Connection
```

And the Subroutine Setup_Connection being something like:

```
Private Sub Setup_Connection
    Dim strConnection as String

    If conn = Nothing Then
        'Choose your own database connection details
        strConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
                "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;" & _
                "Data Source=DATABASESERVER"
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        With conn
            .Open strConnection
            .CommandTimeout = 30
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks K_B, I can use the 2.7 library and can connect to SQL database to get data. However I am puzzled how to avoid duplication of the codes that connect and disconnect from database. kindly advice!